# Aggregating similar records in Spark 1.6.2

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data set where after some transformation by using **Spark SQL (1.6.2)** in **scala** I got following data. (part of data).

```
home away count
a     b    90
b     a    70
c     d    50
e     f    45
f     e    30
```

Now I want to get final result, like aggregating similar `home` and `away` i.e. a and b appearing two times. Similar `home` and `away` may not always come in consecutive rows

```
home    away    count
a        b       160
c        d        50
e        f        75
```

Can someone help me out for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use create a temporary column using `array` and `sort_array` which you can use `groupBy` on to solve this. Here I assumed there can at most be two rows with the same value in the `home`/`away` columns and that which value is in `home` and which is in `away` doesn't matter:

```
val df = Seq(("a", "b", 90),
             ("b", "a", 70),
             ("c", "d", 50),
             ("e", "f", 45),
             ("f", "e", 30)).toDF("home", "away", "count")

val df2 = df.withColumn("home_away", sort_array(array($"home", $"away")))
  .groupBy("home_away")
  .agg(sum("count").as("count"))
  .select($"home_away"(0).as("home"), $"home_away"(1).as("away"), $"count")
  .drop("home_away")
```

Will give:

```
+----+----+-----+
|home|away|count|
+----+----+-----+
|   e|   f|   75|
|   c|   d|   50|
|   a|   b|  160|
+----+----+-----+
```